# Deployer docs are incorrect. How do I properly reconfigure an existing task?

Tags: php, php-deployer

The PHP Deployer docs on [this page](https://deployer.org/docs/tasks) are wrong.

In the section labeled "Reconfigure" it says:

> You can reconfigure tasks, e.g. provided by 3rd part recipes by retrieving them by name:

```
task('notify')->onlyOn([
    'firstserver',
    'thirdserver',
]);
```

This simply does not work with the current version. I get an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
function Deployer\task(), 1 passed in /home/vagrant/Code/MyProject
/deploy.php on line 78 and exactly 2 expected in /home/vagrant
/Code/MyProject/vendor/deployer/deployer/src/functions.php:143
```

Looking at the vendor src file, the `task()` function does indeed require two arguments. It does not act as a getter when passing only one argument.

Is there any (existing) way to get a task and reconfigure it as intended in the docs? What is the correct version? I tried using `get` instead of `task`:

```
get($taskName)->onlyOn([...])
```

But that does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have the latest version? The optional argument `body` was introduced in this commit [#c37237](https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/commit/c37237da8853cb23934e8cbb93441f6e026037f5). Before that the argument was required.

That commit is only one day old, so it may seem like you need to use the `dev-master` version in your Composer file.

> composer require deployer/deployer:dev-master

Edit: Also the related [documentation](https://github.com/deployphp/docs/commit/5daefb59edbaa751bbc36bf5f235ff590748c8a9) was updated yesterday. Unless you have a version newer than that, you are looking at docs that does not fit your environment.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I'm using the official composer version (latest version) but it has not been updated yet. Guess I'll have to wait. I did find a workaround for now, but since it is a bit hacky, I will not post it here unless someone replies and asks for it. Your solution would probably be better for them for now.